# "Skip to main content" link not working anymore

Tags: firefox, google-search

I used to skip to the first search result after a Google search using <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, however as of today, 2022-08-23, that link is not functional anymore using Firefox Developer Edition 104.0b9 (64-bite) for Arch Linux.
The link is still there but nothing happens when I hit enter or even click on it with the mouse. This happens even in troubleshooting mode, where all extensions are deactivated.

Edit: @pbies: The dev console contains multiple occurrences of the following:

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive.
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'report-sample'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “https:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “http:” within script-src: ‘strict-dynamic’ specified
Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘require-trusted-types-for’
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘require-trusted-types-for’
Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified
Some cookies are misusing the “SameSite“ attribute, so it won’t work as expected 4
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/scroll-linked_effects.html for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!
```

Comment: Are you getting 204 error "No content" in dev console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping to main content works again since September 13, 2022.
I never found out why it stopped working or why it works again now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same on different web browsers. Seems like an issue on the Google's side. Error messages don't give any specific info which could be related to the problem.

In result you need a workaround.